# Why $\nu(a)$ is a function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, supremum-and-infimum

Fixed $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and let consider
$$\nu(a)=\sup\{b\in\mathbb{R} : F(a, b)\ge 0\}$$
for a suitable function $F$.

My professor said that $\nu$ is a function. It is not clear for me how to see $\nu$ as a function. What associates and to whom?

I am sorry for my possibly dumb question, but I am a little bit confused.

I hope someone could help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In order to view $\nu$ as a function, you need to consider $a$ to be _variable_ rather than fixed. On the other hand, $F$ must be fixed.

Comment: Let $F$ be given. To every real $a$, associate the supremum over all real numbers $b$ satisfying $F(a,b)\ge 0$.

Comment: Please use descriptive titles. This title says nothing about the subject of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Without further information about $F$ one cannot really give an answer.

It *seems* that $F$ is a function $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, otherwise it does not make much sense to consider the expression $\sup\{b\in\mathbb{R} : F(a, b)\ge 0\}$ for each fixed $a \in \mathbb R$.

The function $\nu$ assigns to each $a \in \mathbb R$ the value $\nu(a) = \sup\{b\in\mathbb{R} : F(a, b)\ge 0\}$. But what is $\sup\{b\in\mathbb{R} : F(a, b)\ge 0\}$?

1. It could be that $\sup\{b\in\mathbb{R} : F(a, b)\ge 0\} = \infty$. This can only happen if $F$ is unbounded.
2. It could be that $\{b\in\mathbb{R} : F(a, b)\ge 0\} = \emptyset$ for some $a$ in which case $\nu(a) = - \infty$.

Thus in general $\nu$ is a function
$$\nu : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty,\infty\}$$
to the extended real line. With suitable assumptions on $F$ we can exclude that $\nu(a)$ takes values in $\{-\infty,\infty\}$. In that case we get a function
$$\nu : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R .$$